# Colour definition in LaTeX- xcolor.sty, svgnam.def, and \definecolor

Tags: color, r

I'm looking for the best way to define a new colour in LaTeX using the different methods above. In xcolor.sty, I have

```
\definecolorset{gray/rgb/hsb/cmyk}{}{}%
 {black,0/0,0,0/0,0,0/0,0,0,1;%
  darkgray,.25/.25,.25,.25/0,0,.25/0,0,0,.75;%
  gray,.5/.5,.5,.5/0,0,.5/0,0,0,.5;%
  lightgray,.75/.75,.75,.75/0,0,.75/0,0,0,.25;%
  white,1/1,1,1/0,0,1/0,0,0,0}
```

And in svgnam.def I have

```
\def\colornameprefix{XC@}
\preparecolorset{rgb}{}{}{%
AliceBlue,.94,.972,1;%
AntiqueWhite,.98,.92,.844;%
Aqua,0,1,1;%
\endinput
```

I want to define a new colour LightBlue directly in my document, but the following R code does not work. Since the white text shows up where it is supposed to, the error must be in the definition of LightBlue:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightBlue}{RGB}{126,160,216}

temp<-read.table(text=paste("Action      Weight
                      1  Addition     1
                      2  Deletion     2
                      3  UpWeight     3 
                      4  DownWeight   4",sep=""),header=TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(temp)){
    if(nrow(temp)>0){
      temp[,1:ncol(temp)]<-"{\\cellcolor{LightBlue}\\textcolor{white}{  }}"
      temp[,2]<-paste0("{\\cellcolor{LightBlue}\\textcolor{white}{to test}}")
      temp$Action<-NULL
    }
  }
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there an error in my current definition?
2. Should I directly define LightBlue in svgnam.def to avoid converting to the four different colour schemes in xcolor.sty?
3. Does {RGB} use a scale from 0 to 255 while {rgb} goes from 0 to 1? If so, would the conversion to {rgb} be as easy as dividing each {RGB} value by 255?

Thank you!

Comment: You've called the colour `RBCLightBlue`

Comment: Oops, it's defined as LightBlue in the document but I copied the wrong line over in my minimal example- thanks for the catch!

Comment: @Anna What error message do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error message, but I get the text "LightBlue" in the cell where is it supposed to be coloured LightBlue instead. For the text "to test", it correctly shows up in white.

Comment: You should first get it working in a latex document without R and once that is working you can check the R code is generating the correct tex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure, I reinstalled the xcolor package, deleted extra calls of \usepackage, and the combination of the two seemed to work